# What's the best way to debug unwanted output in php app (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working in a somewhat big php Laravel application. I have noticed that somewhere in the code there is likely some output being made that results in an unwanted linebreak at the top of any response from the app (both http and console):

```
// Controller
return response('12345');
```

```
    <-- this
12345
```

What would be the best way to debug this - and to your experience what's the most likely culprit?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Search `<-- this` in your project main folders in your text editor/IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is any file that has the linebreak before the `<?php` tag.

If the line break is present on every output, then you should check the files in the config folder.

You can also do a search via grep + regex `\n.*<\?php`. if you'"re on windows, use grepwin.

Comment: You were right about it being a problem with one of the config files. This had been annoying me for months - so thank you so much for the tip!